# SwiftUi Extra Argument in Call When calling two views of @EnvironmentObject in main view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment, environmentobject

When calling one view environment object in main view thats ok build successful but when I call second view environment object its throw an error extra argument in call.

```
struct mainView: View{

    @EnvironmentObject var userInterestVM: User_Interests_ViewModel
  

    var body: some View {
        FirstEnvironmentObjectView()
        FirstEnvironmentObjectView()      //<--(error: Extra Argument in call)

        // if i call first environment with argument like that

        FirstEnvironment(UserInterestsVM: <what I put here>)  
        // what should I put in the argument)
     
    }
}


struct FirstEnvironmentObjectView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var UserInterestsVM: User_Interests_ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("check by default values of model.").onTapGesture {
            print("fitness \(UserInterestsVM.fitness)")    
    }
}


struct FirstEnvironmentObjectView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        testing()
            .environmentObject(User_Interests_ViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put nothing there - environment objects are injected automatically

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just throw in several views into the `body` of a `View`. How would those views be displayed?

You need to wrap them in a stack, depending on your needs, either a `VStack`, `HStack` or `ZStack`.

If you want them to be vertically stacked for instance, use a `VStack`.

```
struct MainView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userInterestVM: User_Interests_ViewModel
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FirstEnvironmentObjectView()
            FirstEnvironmentObjectView()     
        }
    }
}
```

As for the environment object, you don't need to manually inject them into `FirstEnvironmentObjectView` from `MainView`, because `EnvironmentObject`s are injected into the view hierarchy downstream (so to all subviews of the parent view) and hence by injecting a `User_Interests_ViewModel` as an `EnvironmentObject` into `MainView`, it gets automatically injected into all `FirstEnvironmentObjectView`s created inside `MainView`.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate you, its work!.